# use a saved range from a RefEDit

Tags: excel, vba

In a macro, there is a refEdit field. It's value is saved for futur use in an excel cell, so next time the macro is used it is not necessary to select again the range.

The "range" saved has this form : "tab name'!$B$3:$J$21". But this is not recognized in a Range (Range("tab name'!$B$3:$J$21")). What is the best way to used it? Is it necessary to split the tab name and the range cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are going to do with that range:

a) to select if you are in the same sheet:

```
range("'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21").select
```

b) to select is you are not in 'tab name' sheet:

```
application.Goto evaluate("'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21")
```

you could do some more tricks with evaluate like

c) get the name of the sheet:

```
debug.print  evaluate("'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21").parent.name
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I am looking for is to save the range in a variant. With range("'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21"), I get an error on _global object, I do: varModel = Range(modeleRange) where modeleRange = "'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21". I tried adding .select, the same error occur.

Comment: have you tried my code? do some test to understand it, please... you can create `object variable` to save reference to the range but if you have no experience in that area so google for that first (this would do the trick `set rngVariable = evaluate("'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21")`)

Comment: My question was not writen properly. I have a string variable with the reference saved in it: `modeleRange =  "'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21"`. `Set varModel = Range(modeleRange)` throw an error but `Set varModel = Range("'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21")` works.

Comment: not such a situation on my machine. both solutions working fine. I have no idea what is going wrong on your computer.

Comment: I found the root of the issue. When saving `"'tab name'!$B$3:$J$21"` in a cell, the first `'` is removed. So, when loading `tab name'!$B$3:$J$21` from the cell, it's needed to add `' +` in front.